# How to validate data in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-administration

I have an issue related to data in sql server. In my database some of the constraint were not enabled i.e. they were not checked , After some time working on it we found this issue that a parent rows can be deleted without deleting child, which was an issue. I enabled all the constraint in the database using query

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

above query was executed on all the tables of that database without any error . But my concern is whether it will work or not , if it will work on the existing data then what will happen to that data whose parent table data has been deleted.

I want to know is there any way such that I can validate such data data whose parent record doesn't exist in the entire database. There are about `270 constraint` containing `FOREIGN KEY AND UNIQUE KEY` . I don't want to go for manual option.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

only re-enables the constraints. Importantly, the constraints *are not* checked against the existing data in the database (nor are they trusted by the optimizer). If you want that to occur, you need to specify `WITH CHECK` as well:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

(And yes, the word `CHECK` appears twice)

If you execute this, and there are orphaned child rows (or other invalid constraints), then the `ALTER TABLE` will fail with an error message. There's nothing SQL Server can do to fix this issue - it's for you to decide whether to a) remove the orphaned rows, or b) to re-create, in some manner, a suitable parent row for them.

Comment: Hi Damien_The_Unbeliever, Can You please tell me the difference between two ALTER TABLE tbl_name CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
AND ALTER TABLE tbl_name WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

Comment: As I said in my second sentence - the difference is that the first will *not* validate any existing data in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the 'ON DELETE CASCADE' code to the end of foreign keys to prevent orphaned child rows from persisting.

This is more of a 'better practice' going forward than a solution, but I believe Damien_The_Unbeliever has answered your main question.

Comment: It is ok but what about the existing data...Your suggestion will work on further or new data.

Comment: For the existing data I would go with Damien_The_Unbeliever's suggestion